Help Driving 1.52 Inch Eink Display
I am trying to write my own driver for a Pervasive display eink panel using their application note for small epd.
Notice that my panel,SE2152JS0J1
salvaged eink panel,
is nowhere to be mentioned on their website, nor can i find any further documentation.
This panel came off a digital shelf label - a Vusion 1.5 BWR BU431 digital shelf label which from their data sheets 1.5 appears to be 200 by 200 with 2 pages.
I know Pervasive makes their panels because from a larger digital shelf label i managed to write correct driving code for it based on Pervasives driving sheet and it displays generated arrays properly.
Larger Eink working code achieved.
If this panel is made by Pervasive and it is a spectra panel I'm assuming the same commands to the same registers as all of their smaller epds get grouped into one category and share the same initialization and command sequences.
From Pervasive displays, their driving sheet for small epds:
Driving PDF.
Pervasive driver for small EPD and their library suite can easily be found on github but I can only link 8 things here. My work is based off of their small EPD driving code as well as their main library suite.
What I'm having trouble with is writing code that follows their strict commands and delays provided in the driving document and get the display to turn red by sending an all white buffer and then an all red buffer.
Breakdown of the Model Number for the 1.52 SE2152JS0J1 can be decoded as follows:
S: This prefix indicates it's a Pervasive Displays screen.
E2152: The "2152" part suggests the screen size in hundredths of an inch. In this case:
152 corresponds to a 1.52-inch display.
J: This indicates the film type:
According to the header, J stands for Spectra film, specifically black-white-red.
S0J: The driver type:
S0J corresponds to Driver J in the header file, which is typically a wide temperature range and Spectra film driver.
1: This might indicate a specific variant or revision number.
So, SE2152JS0J1 corresponds to:
Size: 1.52 inches (SIZE_152)
Film: Spectra J (black-white-red, denoted by FILM_J)
Driver: Driver J (DRIVER_J)
The closest I've been able to get was to make the outside border of the display turn red, flash really fast and previous frame data remains on the rest of display. On the big working edp when I send it an array it flashes and then it draws it fine.
This is the working code for the larger display that uses slightly different sequences.   It is a 7.4 inch display.

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <pgmspace.h> // Include this header for PROGMEM

// Define pins for ESP32 (adjust according to your wiring)
const uint8_t panelBusy = 21;   // EPD Busy pin (input)
const uint8_t panelDC = 15;     // EPD DC pin (A0)
const uint8_t panelReset = 2;   // EPD Reset pin
const uint8_t panelCS = 17;     // EPD CS pin

const uint8_t spiMosi = 23;     // SPI MOSI
const uint8_t spiMiso = 19;     // SPI MISO (not used)
const uint8_t spiSck = 18;      // SPI SCK

// Include your image arrays stored in PROGMEM to save RAM
const uint8_t image_740_800x480_BWR_blackBuffer[] PROGMEM = {

};

const uint8_t image_740_800x480_BWR_redBuffer[] PROGMEM = {

};

void setup() {
  // Initialize serial for debugging
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial); // Wait for serial port to connect
  Serial.println("Starting EPD test");

  // Initialize EPD
  COG_initial();

  // Display the image
  globalUpdate_Image();

  // Turn off EPD
  COG_powerOff();
}

void loop() {
  // Do nothing
}

// Function to initialize the EPD
void COG_initial() {
  Serial.println("Initializing EPD...");

  // Initialize pins
  pinMode(panelBusy, INPUT); // Use external pull-up resistor if required
  pinMode(panelDC, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(panelDC, HIGH);
  pinMode(panelReset, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(panelReset, HIGH);
  pinMode(panelCS, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(panelCS, HIGH);

  // Initialize SPI
  SPI.begin(spiSck, spiMiso, spiMosi, panelCS);

  Serial.println("COG initialization complete");
}

// Function to send command and data to the EPD via SPI
void sendIndexData(uint8_t index, const uint8_t *data, uint32_t len) {
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(5000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0)); // SPI speed at 5 MHz

  // Send Index (Command)
  digitalWrite(panelDC, LOW);    // A0 LOW for Index (Command)
  digitalWrite(panelCS, LOW);    // CS Low
  SPI.transfer(index);
  digitalWrite(panelCS, HIGH);   // CS High

  // Send Data if available
  if (len > 0 && data != NULL) {
    digitalWrite(panelDC, HIGH);   // A0 HIGH for Data
    digitalWrite(panelCS, LOW);    // CS Low
    SPI.writeBytes(data, len);
    digitalWrite(panelCS, HIGH);   // CS High
  }

  SPI.endTransaction();
}

// Adjusted function to read from PROGMEM
void sendIndexDataFromProgmem(uint8_t index, const uint8_t *data, uint32_t len) {
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(5000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));

  // Send Index (Command)
  digitalWrite(panelDC, LOW);
  digitalWrite(panelCS, LOW);
  SPI.write(index);
  digitalWrite(panelCS, HIGH);

  // Send Data if available
  if (len > 0 && data != NULL) {
    digitalWrite(panelDC, HIGH);   // A0 HIGH for Data
    digitalWrite(panelCS, LOW);    // CS Low

    uint8_t buffer[256];
    uint32_t bytesSent = 0;
    while (bytesSent < len) {
      uint32_t bytesToSend = (len - bytesSent > 256) ? 256 : (len - bytesSent);
      memcpy_P(buffer, data + bytesSent, bytesToSend);
      SPI.writeBytes(buffer, bytesToSend);  // Send entire buffer
      bytesSent += bytesToSend;
    }

    digitalWrite(panelCS, HIGH);   // CS High
  }

  SPI.endTransaction();
}

// Function to reset the EPD
void resetEPD() {
  Serial.println("Resetting EPD...");
  digitalWrite(panelReset, LOW);  // Reset the display (active LOW)
  delay(200);                     // Hold reset low for at least 200 ms
  digitalWrite(panelReset, HIGH); // Release reset
  delay(200);                     // Wait after reset
  digitalWrite(panelCS, HIGH);
  delay(5);
}

// Function to perform DC-DC soft start
void DCDC_softStart_Mid() {
  Serial.println("Starting DC-DC Soft Start...");
  uint8_t data4[] = {0x7d};
  sendIndexData(0x05, data4, 1);
  delay(200);
  uint8_t data5[] = {0x00};
  sendIndexData(0x05, data5, 1);
  delay(10);
  uint8_t data6[] = {0x3f};
  sendIndexData(0xc2, data6, 1);
  delay(1);
  uint8_t data7[] = {0x00};
  sendIndexData(0xd8, data7, 1);
  sendIndexData(0xd6, data7, 1);
  uint8_t data9[] = {0x10};
  sendIndexData(0xa7, data9 , 1);
  delay(100);
  sendIndexData(0xa7, data5, 1);
  delay(100);

  uint8_t data10[] = {0x00, 0x01};
  sendIndexData(0x03, data10, 2);

  sendIndexData(0x44, data5, 1);
  uint8_t data11[] = {0x80};
  sendIndexData(0x45, data11, 1);
  sendIndexData(0xa7, data9, 1);
  delay(100);
  sendIndexData(0xa7, data7, 1);
  delay(100);
  uint8_t data12[] = {0x06};
  sendIndexData(0x44, data12, 1);
  uint8_t data13[] = {0x82};
  sendIndexData(0x45, data13, 1);
  sendIndexData(0xa7, data9, 1);
  delay(100);
  sendIndexData(0xa7, data7, 1);
  delay(100);
  uint8_t data14[] = {0x25};
  sendIndexData(0x60, data14, 1);

  uint8_t data15[] = {0x00};
  sendIndexData(0x61, data15, 1);

  sendIndexData(0x01, data15, 1);
  sendIndexData(0x02, data15, 1);

  uint8_t index51[] = {0x50, 0x01, 0x0a, 0x01};
  sendIndexData(0x51, &index51[0], 2);
  uint8_t index09[] = {0x1f, 0x9f, 0x7f, 0xff};

  for (int value = 1; value <= 4; value++) {
    sendIndexData(0x09, &index09[0], 1);
    index51[1] = value;
    sendIndexData(0x51, &index51[0], 2);
    sendIndexData(0x09, &index09[1], 1);
    delay(2);
  }
  for (int value = 1; value <= 10; value++) {
    sendIndexData(0x09, &index09[0], 1);
    index51[3] = value;
    sendIndexData(0x51, &index51[2], 2);
    sendIndexData(0x09, &index09[1], 1);
    delay(2);
  }
  for (int value = 3; value <= 10; value++) {
    sendIndexData(0x09, &index09[2], 1);
    index51[3] = value;
    sendIndexData(0x51, &index51[2], 2);
    sendIndexData(0x09, &index09[3], 1);
    delay(2);
  }
  for (int value = 9; value >= 2; value--) {
    sendIndexData(0x09, &index09[2], 1);
    index51[2] = value;
    sendIndexData(0x51, &index51[2], 2);
    sendIndexData(0x09, &index09[3], 1);
    delay(2);
  }
  sendIndexData(0x09, &index09[3], 1);
  delay(10);
  Serial.println("DC-DC Soft Start Complete");
}

// Function to refresh the display
void displayRefresh() {
  Serial.println("Refreshing display...");
  unsigned long startTime = millis();
  Serial.print("displayRefresh: panelBusy before loop: ");
  Serial.println(digitalRead(panelBusy));
  while (digitalRead(panelBusy) == LOW) { // Wait while BUSY is LOW
    if (millis() - startTime > 30000) { // Timeout after 30 seconds
      Serial.println("Error: displayRefresh timeout");
      break;
    }
    Serial.print("displayRefresh: panelBusy in loop: ");
    Serial.println(digitalRead(panelBusy));
    delay(100);
  }
  uint8_t data18[] = {0x3c};
  sendIndexData(0x15, data18, 1);
  delay(5);
  Serial.println("Display refresh command sent");
}

// Function to perform DC-DC soft shutdown
void DCDC_softShutdown_Mid() {
  Serial.println("Starting DC-DC Soft Shutdown...");
  unsigned long startTime = millis();
  Serial.print("DCDC_softShutdown_Mid: panelBusy before loop: ");
  Serial.println(digitalRead(panelBusy));

  // Wait for panelBusy to go HIGH before starting shutdown
  while (digitalRead(panelBusy) == LOW) {
    if (millis() - startTime > 30000) { // Timeout after 30 seconds
      Serial.println("Error: DCDC_softShutdown_Mid timeout");
      break;
    }
    Serial.print("DCDC_softShutdown_Mid: panelBusy in loop: ");
    Serial.println(digitalRead(panelBusy));
    delay(100);
  }

  // Send shutdown commands
  uint8_t data19[] = {0x7f};
  sendIndexData(0x09, data19, 1);
  delay(100); // Added delay
  uint8_t data20[] = {0x7d};
  sendIndexData(0x05, data20, 1);
  delay(100); // Added delay
  uint8_t data55[] = {0x00};
  sendIndexData(0x09, data55, 1);
  delay(500); // Increased delay

  // Wait again for panelBusy to go HIGH
  startTime = millis();
  Serial.print("DCDC_softShutdown_Mid: panelBusy before second loop: ");
  Serial.println(digitalRead(panelBusy));
  while (digitalRead(panelBusy) == LOW) {
    if (millis() - startTime > 30000) {
      Serial.println("Error: DCDC_softShutdown_Mid timeout after delay");
      break;
    }
    Serial.print("DCDC_softShutdown_Mid: panelBusy in second loop: ");
    Serial.println(digitalRead(panelBusy));
    delay(100);
  }

  // Finalize shutdown
  digitalWrite(panelDC, LOW);
  digitalWrite(panelCS, LOW);
  digitalWrite(panelReset, LOW);
  digitalWrite(panelCS, HIGH);
  Serial.println("DC-DC Soft Shutdown Complete");
}

// Function to perform a global update with image data
void globalUpdate_Image() {
  Serial.println("Performing global image update...");
  resetEPD();

  uint8_t dtcl = 0x08;
  sendIndexData(0x01, &dtcl, 1);

  uint8_t data1[] = {0x00, 0x3b, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1f, 0x03};
  sendIndexData(0x13, data1, 6);
  uint8_t data2[] = {0x00, 0x3b, 0x00, 0xc9};
  sendIndexData(0x90, data2, 4);
  uint8_t data3[] = {0x3b, 0x00, 0x14};
  sendIndexData(0x12, data3, 3);

  // Send black layer data
  Serial.println("Sending black layer data...");
  sendIndexDataFromProgmem(0x10, image_740_800x480_BWR_blackBuffer, sizeof(image_740_800x480_BWR_blackBuffer));

  // Send red layer data (changed register index from 0x13 to 0x11)
  Serial.println("Sending red layer data...");
  sendIndexDataFromProgmem(0x11, image_740_800x480_BWR_redBuffer, sizeof(image_740_800x480_BWR_redBuffer));

  DCDC_softStart_Mid();

  displayRefresh();

  // Increase delay to allow display to complete refresh
  delay(5000); // Delay for 5 seconds

  // Check if panelBusy is LOW before starting shutdown
  if (digitalRead(panelBusy) == LOW) {
    Serial.println("Warning: panelBusy is LOW before shutdown, adding delay...");
    delay(5000); // Wait additional time for display to become ready
  }

  DCDC_softShutdown_Mid();
  Serial.println("Global image update complete");
}

// Function to power off the EPD
void COG_powerOff() {
  Serial.println("Powering off EPD...");

  // Wait until the display is not busy
  unsigned long startTime = millis();
  Serial.print("COG_powerOff: panelBusy before loop: ");
  Serial.println(digitalRead(panelBusy));
  while (digitalRead(panelBusy) == LOW) { // Wait while BUSY is LOW
    if (millis() - startTime > 30000) { // Timeout after 30 seconds
      Serial.println("Error: COG_powerOff timeout");
      break;
    }
    Serial.print("COG_powerOff: panelBusy in loop: ");
    Serial.println(digitalRead(panelBusy));
    delay(100);
  }

  // Step 1: Send SPI(0x09, 0x7F)
  uint8_t data_7F[] = {0x7F};
  sendIndexData(0x09, data_7F, 1);

  // Step 2: Send SPI(0x05, 0x3D)
  uint8_t data_3D[] = {0x3D};
  sendIndexData(0x05, data_3D, 1);

  // Step 3: Send SPI(0x09, 0x7E)
  uint8_t data_7E[] = {0x7E};
  sendIndexData(0x09, data_7E, 1);

  // Step 4: Delay for 15 ms
  delay(15);

  // Step 5: Send SPI(0x09, 0x00)
  uint8_t data_00[] = {0x00};
  sendIndexData(0x09, data_00, 1);

  // Set all control pins to LOW
  digitalWrite(panelDC, LOW);
  digitalWrite(panelCS, LOW);
  // Do not set panelBusy, as it is an input pin
  delay(150);
  digitalWrite(panelReset, LOW);

  Serial.println("EPD powered off");
}

This code was based off of the 7.4 driving document.
It properly displays arrays generated from images using this python code I wrote
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import os
import hashlib

# Correct Display dimensions
DISPLAY_WIDTH = 480   # Width of the display in pixels
DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 800  # Height of the display in pixels

def image_to_buffers(image_path):
    # Open and resize the image
    img = Image.open(image_path)
    img = img.resize((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT), resample=Image.LANCZOS)
    img = img.convert('RGB')  # Ensure it's in RGB mode

    # Convert image data to arrays
    pixels = np.array(img)

    # Initialize buffers
    black_buffer = np.zeros((DISPLAY_HEIGHT, DISPLAY_WIDTH), dtype=np.uint8)
    color_buffer = np.zeros((DISPLAY_HEIGHT, DISPLAY_WIDTH), dtype=np.uint8)

    # Define color thresholds
    black_threshold = 85
    color_threshold = 150

    # Create masks for black and color pixels
    black_mask = (pixels[:, :, 0] < black_threshold) & \
                 (pixels[:, :, 1] < black_threshold) & \
                 (pixels[:, :, 2] < black_threshold)

    color_mask = (pixels[:, :, 0] > color_threshold) & \
                 (pixels[:, :, 1] < black_threshold) & \
                 (pixels[:, :, 2] < black_threshold)

    # Apply masks to buffers
    black_buffer[black_mask] = 1
    color_buffer[color_mask] = 1

    return black_buffer, color_buffer

def buffer_to_c_array(buffer, array_name):
    c_array = f'const uint8_t image_480_800_BWR_{array_name}[] PROGMEM = {{\n'
    count = 0
    line = ''
    for y in tqdm(range(DISPLAY_HEIGHT), desc=f"Processing {array_name}"):
        for x in range(0, DISPLAY_WIDTH, 8):
            byte = 0
            for bit in range(8):
                if x + bit < DISPLAY_WIDTH:
                    byte |= (buffer[y][x + bit] << (7 - bit))  # D7 first pixel
                else:
                    byte |= (0 << (7 - bit))  # Padding with 0
            line += f'0x{byte:02X}, '
            count += 1
            if count % 16 == 0:
                c_array += '    ' + line.rstrip() + '\n'
                line = ''
    if line:
        c_array += '    ' + line.rstrip() + '\n'
    c_array += '};\n'
    return c_array

def create_header_file(black_buffer, color_buffer, output_filename):
    with open(output_filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write('#ifndef EINK_IMAGE_BUFFERS_H\n')
        f.write('#define EINK_IMAGE_BUFFERS_H\n\n')
        f.write('#include <Arduino.h>\n')
        f.write('#include <pgmspace.h>\n\n')
        
        # Write black buffer
        black_c_array = buffer_to_c_array(black_buffer, 'blackBuffer')
        f.write(black_c_array + '\n')
        
        # Write color buffer
        color_c_array = buffer_to_c_array(color_buffer, 'colorBuffer')
        f.write(color_c_array + '\n')
        
        f.write('#endif // EINK_IMAGE_BUFFERS_H\n')

def compute_checksum(buffer):
    return hashlib.md5(buffer.tobytes()).hexdigest()

def main():
    # Path to your image file
    image_path = './chondore.png'  # Use forward slashes for cross-platform compatibility

    if not os.path.exists(image_path):
        print(f"Error: Image file '{image_path}' does not exist.")
        return

    # Output filename for the header file
    header_output_filename = 'eink_image_buffers.h'

    # Generate buffers
    black_buffer, color_buffer = image_to_buffers(image_path)

    # Verify buffer sizes (number of pixels)
    actual_size_black = black_buffer.size
    actual_size_color = color_buffer.size

    print(f"Black Buffer Size (pixels): {actual_size_black} bytes")
    print(f"Color Buffer Size (pixels): {actual_size_color} bytes")

    # Expected number of pixels
    expected_pixels = DISPLAY_WIDTH * DISPLAY_HEIGHT  # 480 * 800 = 384,000
    if actual_size_black != expected_pixels or actual_size_color != expected_pixels:
        print(f"Error: Buffer sizes do not match expected pixel count ({expected_pixels}).")
        return

    # Convert buffers to a header file and save
    create_header_file(black_buffer, color_buffer, header_output_filename)

    print(f'Header file saved to {header_output_filename}')

    # Compute and print checksums
    black_checksum = compute_checksum(black_buffer)
    color_checksum = compute_checksum(color_buffer)
    print(f"Black Buffer Checksum: {black_checksum}")
    print(f"Color Buffer Checksum: {color_checksum}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


Now this code fills the border with red as I mentioned earlier and it is the only iteration that I can get any sort of visual response from the display,  but it does not follow the correct driving sequence
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <pgmspace.h>

// Display constants
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 200
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 200
#define BUFFER_SIZE (SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT / 8)

// Pin definitions
const uint8_t panelBusy = 21;
const uint8_t panelDC = 15;
const uint8_t panelReset = 2;
const uint8_t panelCS = 17;
const uint8_t spiMosi = 23;
const uint8_t spiMiso = 19;
const uint8_t spiSck = 18;

// COG initialization data
const uint8_t COG_data[] = {
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0F, 0xFF, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x25, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
};

class EPD_152 {
private:
    uint8_t u_temperature = 25;

    void waitBusy(const char* message) {
        Serial.println(message);
        unsigned long startTime = millis();
        while(digitalRead(panelBusy) == LOW) {
            Serial.print(".");
            delay(100);
            if(millis() - startTime > 10000) {
                Serial.println("\nTimeout!");
                return;
            }
        }
        Serial.println("Done!");
    }

    void sendCommand(uint8_t command) {
        digitalWrite(panelDC, LOW);
        digitalWrite(panelCS, LOW);
        SPI.transfer(command);
        digitalWrite(panelCS, HIGH);
    }

    void sendData(uint8_t data) {
        digitalWrite(panelDC, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(panelCS, LOW);
        SPI.transfer(data);
        digitalWrite(panelCS, HIGH);
    }

    void sendCommandData(uint8_t command, uint8_t data) {
        Serial.printf("CMD: 0x%02X, Data: 0x%02X\n", command, data);
        sendCommand(command);
        sendData(data);
    }

    void sendDataBuffer(const uint8_t* buffer, uint32_t size) {
        digitalWrite(panelDC, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(panelCS, LOW);
        
        uint8_t tempBuffer[256];
        uint32_t bytesSent = 0;
        
        while(bytesSent < size) {
            uint32_t chunk = min(256U, size - bytesSent);
            memcpy_P(tempBuffer, buffer + bytesSent, chunk);
            SPI.writeBytes(tempBuffer, chunk);
            bytesSent += chunk;
        }
        
        digitalWrite(panelCS, HIGH);
    }

public:
    void init() {
        Serial.println("Initializing display...");
        
        pinMode(panelBusy, INPUT);
        pinMode(panelDC, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(panelReset, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(panelCS, OUTPUT);
        
        digitalWrite(panelCS, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(panelDC, HIGH);
        
        SPI.begin(spiSck, spiMiso, spiMosi, panelCS);
        SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(4000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
        
        reset();
    }

    void reset() {
        Serial.println("Reset sequence...");
        digitalWrite(panelReset, HIGH);
        delay(200);
        digitalWrite(panelReset, LOW);
        delay(10);
        digitalWrite(panelReset, HIGH);
        delay(200);
    }

    void updateDisplay(const uint8_t* blackBuffer, const uint8_t* redBuffer) {
        Serial.println("Starting display update...");
        
        // Power on sequence
        sendCommandData(0x05, 0x7d);
        delay(200);
        sendCommandData(0x05, 0x00);
        delay(10);
        
        // Init sequence from EPD_EXT3
        sendCommandData(0xc2, 0x3f);
        delay(1);
        
        sendCommandData(0xd8, COG_data[0x0d]);
        sendCommandData(0xd6, COG_data[0x0e]);
        
        sendCommandData(0xa7, 0x10);
        delay(100);
        sendCommandData(0xa7, 0x00);
        delay(100);
        
        // Temperature settings
        sendCommandData(0x44, 0x06);
        uint8_t tempIndex = u_temperature * 2 + 0x50;
        sendCommandData(0x45, tempIndex);
        
        // Panel settings
        sendCommandData(0x60, COG_data[0x0b]);
        sendCommandData(0x61, COG_data[0x0c]);
        sendCommandData(0x01, COG_data[0x00]);
        sendCommandData(0x02, COG_data[0x01]);
        
        Serial.println("Sending black buffer...");
        sendCommand(0x10);
        sendDataBuffer(blackBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
        
        Serial.println("Sending red buffer...");
        sendCommand(0x11);
        sendDataBuffer(redBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
        
        Serial.println("Updating display...");
        sendCommand(0x20);
        
        waitBusy("Waiting for display refresh...");
    }

    void powerOff() {
        Serial.println("Power off sequence...");
        sendCommandData(0x09, 0x7F);
        delay(100);
        sendCommandData(0x05, 0x3D);
        delay(100);
        sendCommandData(0x09, 0x00);
        
        digitalWrite(panelDC, LOW);
        digitalWrite(panelCS, LOW);
        digitalWrite(panelReset, LOW);
        
        Serial.println("Display powered off");
    }
    
    void setTemperature(uint8_t temp) {
        u_temperature = temp;
    }
};

// Test pattern
const uint8_t testPattern[BUFFER_SIZE] PROGMEM = {
    0xAA, 0x55, 0xAA, 0x55, // Checkerboard pattern
};

EPD_152 display;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    while(!Serial) delay(10);
    Serial.println("\nStarting EPD 1.52 Test");
    
    display.init();
    display.setTemperature(25);
    display.updateDisplay(testPattern, testPattern);
    display.powerOff();
    
    Serial.println("Test complete");
}

void loop() {
    delay(1000);
}


Now an example code for the smaller eink 1.52 that does not produce any visual response but the wave form begin to look some what correct:
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <pgmspace.h>

// Display constants
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 200
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 200
#define BUFFER_SIZE (SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT / 8)

// Pin definitions
const uint8_t panelBusy = 21;
const uint8_t panelDC = 15;
const uint8_t panelReset = 2;
const uint8_t panelCS = 17;
const uint8_t spiMosi = 23;
const uint8_t spiMiso = 19;
const uint8_t spiSck = 18;

// COG initialization data
const uint8_t COG_data[] PROGMEM = {0x0E, 0x82, 0x37, 0x00, 0x23, 0x23, 0xC7, 0xC7, 0x1D, 0xCF, 0x89};

// Image buffer
uint8_t blackBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
uint8_t redBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

class EPD_152 {
private:
    uint8_t u_temperature = 25;

    void waitBusy(const char* message) {
        Serial.println(message);
        while (digitalRead(panelBusy) == LOW) {
            delay(10);
        }
        Serial.println("Done!");
    }

    void sendCommand(uint8_t command) {
        digitalWrite(panelDC, LOW);
        digitalWrite(panelCS, LOW);
        SPI.transfer(command);
        digitalWrite(panelCS, HIGH);
    }

    void sendData(uint8_t data) {
        digitalWrite(panelDC, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(panelCS, LOW);
        SPI.transfer(data);
        digitalWrite(panelCS, HIGH);
    }

    void sendCommandWithData(uint8_t command, const uint8_t* data, uint8_t length) {
        sendCommand(command);
        for (uint8_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            sendData(data[i]);
        }
    }

public:
    void init() {
        Serial.println("Initializing display...");
        pinMode(panelBusy, INPUT);
        pinMode(panelDC, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(panelReset, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(panelCS, OUTPUT);

        digitalWrite(panelCS, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(panelDC, HIGH);

        SPI.begin(spiSck, spiMiso, spiMosi, panelCS);
        SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(4000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));

        reset();
        setupDisplay();
    }

    void reset() {
        Serial.println("Resetting display...");
        digitalWrite(panelReset, HIGH);
        delay(200);
        digitalWrite(panelReset, LOW);
        delay(10);
        digitalWrite(panelReset, HIGH);
        delay(200);
    }

    void setupDisplay() {
        Serial.println("Setting up display...");

        // Send initialization commands
        uint8_t initCommands1[] = {0x0E};
        sendCommandWithData(0x00, initCommands1, 1);

        uint8_t initCommands2[] = {0x82};
        sendCommandWithData(0xE5, initCommands2, 1);

        uint8_t initCommands3[] = {0x37, 0x00, 0x23, 0x23};
        sendCommandWithData(0x01, initCommands3, 4);

        uint8_t initCommands4[] = {0xC7, 0xC7, 0x1D};
        sendCommandWithData(0x06, initCommands4, 3);

        uint8_t initCommands5[] = {0xCF, 0x89};
        sendCommandWithData(0x00, initCommands5, 2);

        uint8_t initCommands6[] = {0x98, 0x00, 0x98};
        sendCommandWithData(0x61, initCommands6, 3);

        uint8_t initCommands7[] = {0x00};
        sendCommandWithData(0x15, initCommands7, 1);

        uint8_t initCommands8[] = {0x37};
        sendCommandWithData(0x50, initCommands8, 1);

        uint8_t initCommands9[] = {0x22};
        sendCommandWithData(0x60, initCommands9, 1);

        Serial.println("Initialization complete.");
    }

    void updateDisplay() {
        Serial.println("Updating display...");

        // Sending black frame
        sendCommand(0x10);
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++) {
            sendData(blackBuffer[i]);
        }

        // Sending red frame
        sendCommand(0x13);
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++) {
            sendData(redBuffer[i]);
        }

        // Refresh display
        sendCommand(0x12);
        waitBusy("Waiting for display refresh...");
    }

    void powerOff() {
        Serial.println("Powering off display...");
        sendCommand(0x02);
        waitBusy("Power off complete.");
    }
};

EPD_152 display;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    while (!Serial);
    Serial.println("Starting EPD Test");

    // Initialize the display
    display.init();

    // Fill buffers with test patterns
    memset(blackBuffer, 0x00, BUFFER_SIZE); // All black
    memset(redBuffer, 0xFF, BUFFER_SIZE);   // All red

    // Update the display with the test pattern
    display.updateDisplay();

    // Power off the display
    display.powerOff();
}

void loop() {
    delay(1000);
}


produces the following
2
3
and I'm expecting their waveform and timings (pls refer to the small epd driving document).
EXT3 Pervasive breakout board is being used.
I really want to get this eink to work but there is very little documentation on this exact model. Going back and forth with AI is driving me crazy - I need some human help. If anyone is able to dedicate some time to figuring this out I'd really appreciate it.
My setup (works and tested with larger display) short on EXT3 extension board removed as per the smaller EPD requirements I have all the correct pin definitions and power is being supplied externally 3.3 via breadboard power supply.
EPD Driving Setup
My only goal right now is to properly display the red buffer and make the screen refresh to red.
